# css keyframes change font-family style

Tags: css-animations, font-family

I'm trying to see if CSS animations will change the font-family. I've googled but no one seems to have a demo for changing the font-family with keyframes. My code isn't working. Do I need more vendor prefixes somewhere?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


<html>
<head>
<title>Font Change</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".css">
<style>
#font 
{
width: 500px;
height: 50px;

-webkit-animation-name: newfont;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-moz-animation-name: newfont;
-moz-animation-duration: 3s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

animation-name: newfont;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-timing-function: ease;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes newfont
{
0% {font-family: "Arial";}
33% {font-family: "Comic Sans MS";}
66% {font-family: "Impact"; }
}


@-moz-keyframes newfont
{
0% {font-family: "Arial";}
33% {font-family: "Comic Sans MS";}
66% {font-family: "Impact"; }
}



@keyframes newfont
{
0% {font-family: "Arial";}
33% {font-family: "Comic Sans MS";}
66% {font-family: "Impact"; }
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="font">
This is some text that has it's font changed with an animation.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's likely not working because no browser supports font-family transitions. Implementing that would be quite complex, especially considering that it isn't very useful in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE8 or less, then this won't work. Those versions of IE do not support a lot of animation declarations. Try updating your IE or using Firefox or Chrome. If you already are doing this, I can't really help you.